# How do I add shortcuts on Desktop in Debian 12 (Bookworm)?

Tags: debian, desktop-environment, desktop

I changed from Kali Linux to simple Debian and I dislike the results so far.

Previously I had shortcuts on the desktop but switching to Debian 12 there are no shortcuts?

How do I add them?

Comment: You should mention at least your desktop environment. Debian is just a distribution. It doesn't define the way you add shortcuts to the desktop.

Comment: Debian's "default" DE is gnome3. Also, Gnome3 is pretty famous for removing the icon-on-desktop feature, but it is very possible to re-enable it.  Search "Add icons to desktop in Gnome3" and you'll find a ton of answers.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing to xfce enviroment.